# Creating Thousands of Individual URLs - Google Drive

Tags: batch, url, shared-folders, google-drive

Case Scenario Google Drive - G Suite

900 Folders – each folder having 2 sub-folders

Each folder and sub-folder containing multiple .jpg images

I need to get a listing of shareable URLs for all images in all folders and sub-folders to put on a spreadsheet.

This can be done by selecting a group of files within a folder and pasting the URL to a spreadsheet, however it would take forever to manage this task for 2700 folders individually.

Currently Google indicates this is not an option offered

Is there a way to batch or script this automatically?

Comment: From what you're saying, I assume you'd need that as a feature from Google's Admin console, which I'm surprised isn't already an option. Off the top of my head, I can see a method using a bash script to loop through the file's urls, but it'd be extremely messy and may result in some form of rate limitation on your end of things. I suggest asking on [Google's forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/googlehome) until it's implemented as a feature.

Comment: Consider using google drives search feature.  You can click the arrow in the search bar at the top to show more options and choose files by file type and by folder location.  Then select all the files in the search results and right-click and download.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use google drive's "start mark" to make this purpose.

1. Go into your folder.
2. Use ctrl+a for selecting all of your file.
3. Use mouse right click and select the "start mark"
4. See your slide panel and go into "start mark". Then, you can see the files you had add "start mark".
5. Do the same thing as the step 2 and use mouse right click to select "share". Then, you can see all of your sharing links.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLDSF.png)